# Join tables with JPA

Tags: java, oracle, jpa

I'm trying to create a JPQL query that gets specific fields from my 3 tables:

> idCurso,nombCurso,fRegistro,idProfesor,nombProfe,idAula,descripcion

My entities JPA:

//TABLE: AULA

```
@Entity
@Table(name="aulas")
public class Aula implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private String id;  
private String descripcion; 
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date fRegistro; 
private Integer estado; 
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "aula",cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
private List<Curso> curso;
```

//TABLE: PROFESOR

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Table(name="profesores")
public class Profesor implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
private String id;  
private String nombProfe;   
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date f_nacimiento;  
private Integer estado; 
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "profesor", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
private List<Curso> curso;
```

//TABLE: CURSO

```
@Entity
@Table(name="cursos")
public class Curso implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private String id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "profesor_id")
@JsonIgnore
private Profesor profesor;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "aula_id")
@JsonIgnore
private Aula aula;

private String nomCurso;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date fRegistro;
```

//REPOSITOY

```
public interface CursoRepositorio extends JpaRepository<Curso, String>{}
```

//SERVICE

```
@Autowired
CursoRepositorio cursoRepositorio;
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
    public Curso buscarById(String id)
    {
        return (Curso) em.createQuery("SELECT c.id,c.nomCurso,c.fRegistro,a.id,a.descripcion,p.id,p.nombProfe FROM Curso c JOIN c.aula a JOIN c.profesor p WHERE c.id= :p1")
                .setParameter("p1", id)


      .getResultList();
}
```

//CONTROLLER

```
@GetMapping("/curso/{id}")
public Curso CursoById(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    return cursoServicio.buscarById(id);

}
```

I tried with this query:

```
SELECT c.id,c.nomCurso,c.fRegistro,a.id,a.descripcion,p.id,p.nombProfe FROM Curso c JOIN c.aula a JOIN c.profesor p WHERE c.id= :p1
```

error(SOAPUI):

> java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.unjfsc.rest.model.Curso

I think maybe I should create a temporary table to make the query easier, but how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast `List` on `Curso` class.
To fix this issue you should do the following:

`List<Object[]> results = em.createQuery("SELECT c.id,c.nomCurso,c.fRegistro,a.id,a.descripcion,p.id,p.nombProfe FROM Curso c JOIN c.aula a JOIN c.profesor p WHERE c.id= :p1").setParameter("p1", id).getResultList();`

And subsequently, do appropriate mapping, and return properly initialized object from your method.